# How to pass the correct data format from SQL to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, highcharts

I need to create a [basic column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) using highcharts. Here's my PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT campaign_id, kpi, label, val FROM table WHERE id = $1";

$result = pg_prepare($db, "report", $query);
$result = pg_execute($db, "report", array($campaignID));

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $response['xlabels'][] = $row['label'];
    $response['xdata'][] = (float)$row['val'];
}

pg_free_result($result);
pg_close($db);

echo json_encode($response);
```

The PostgreSQL query returns data as follows (campaign_id = 5, for instance):

```
 id |    kpi    | label | val  
----+-----------+-------+------
  5 | Voter     | East  | 0.18 
  5 | Non-Voter | East  | 0.12 
  5 | Voter     | West  | 0.82 
  5 | Non-Voter | West  | 0.88
```

My API saves `xlabels` and `xdata` to `xAxis.categories`and `series`:

```
$.get('vote_api.php', {'id' : id}, function(data) {

    options.chart.type = 'column';

    options.xAxis.categories = data.xlabels;
    options.series = data.xdata;   

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    }, "json");
```

The right data format for `kpi` (Voter vs. Non-Voter) as my series and `label` (East vs West) as my xAxis should be (please refer to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)):

```
xAxis.categories = ['East', 'West'];
series = [{name: 'Voter',
            data: [0.18, 0.82]},
          {name: 'Non-Voter',
            data: [0.12, 0.88]}]
```

However my `while loop` part `$response['xlabels'][] = $row['label']; $response['xdata'][] = (float)$row['val'];` give me something like this:

```
[xlabels] => Array
    (
        [0] => East
        [1] => East
        [2] => West
        [3] => West
    )

[xdata] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.18
        [1] => 0.12
        [2] => 0.82
        [3] => 0.88
    )
```

Would some one give some hints how to do this? I'd really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try :

```
$query = "SELECT campaign_id, kpi, label, val FROM table WHERE id = $1";

$result = pg_prepare($db, "report", $query);
$result = pg_execute($db, "report", array($campaignID));

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    if (!in_array($row['label'], $response['xlabels']))
    {
        $response['xlabels'][] = $row['label'];
    }
    $response['xdata'][ $row['kpi'] ][] = (float)$row['val'];
}

pg_free_result($result);
pg_close($db);
```

The first change :

```
    if (!in_array($row['label'], $response['xlabels']))
    {
        $response['xlabels'][] = $row['label'];
    }
```

avoids to save several times "East" and "West" to your xlabels array.

The second change :

```
    $response['xdata'][ $row['kpi'] ][] = (float)$row['val'];
```

Will add a dimension to the xdata array : values are assigned to different arrays according to their "kpi".

Comment: Thanks a lot Alain. This greatly helps me. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry Alain, I'm still trying to debug the correct format. I think what I really need is some thing like: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Voter
            [data] => Array
  (
   0.18, 0.82
  )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Non-Voter
            [data] => Array
  (
   0.12, 0.88
  )
        )
)` so that JSON can encode it as: `{name: 'Voter', data: [0.18, 0.82]},
{name: 'Non-Voter', data: [0.12, 0.88]}`. I'm using your code but it doesn't specify the `name` and `data`. Can you help on this? Thanks!

Comment: add this after all other code:
`$final = array();
foreach ($response as $name => $data)
{
 $elem = new stdClass();
 $elem->name = $name;
 $elem->data = $data;
 $final[] = $elem;
}`

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much Alain! Actually the code adds `name` and `data` to every element of `$response` including `xlabels`. So I modified it to `foreach($response['xdata']...` and replace `$response['xdata']` with `$final`. Anyhow, it works like a charm now. Nothing can express my gratitude!! You have a wonderful day!